# Python: Saving an Excel file with the current date

Tags: python, excel, datetime

I'm trying to save a new Excel File in the same folder with the original file name and current date, using Python 3.6 and the Datetime module.

The file is saved, but when I open the created file it says Excel cannot open the file 'AllData 2017_08_04.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid.

How can I get the file to save correctly with the datestring included?

```
from datetime import datetime

os.chdir(r'\\URL\All Data Folder')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('AllData.xlsm')
datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), ' %Y_%m_%d')
wb.save('AllData' + datestring + '.xlsm')
```

Comment: what happens if you use a `.xlsx` extension? The Macros may be affecting your desired output.

Comment: I'm thinking that's the problem. I just tried on my own `.xlsx` file and it worked just fine.

Comment: Read About [Note: The following will fail:](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your issue. Use pandas instead

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#Use pandas to adress the issue

os.chdir(r'\\URL\All Data Folder')
wb=pd.read_excel(io=r"YOUR PATH\AllData.xlsm")#Fill in your path
datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), ' %Y_%m_%d')

wb.to_excel(excel_writer=r"YOUR PATH\{0}".format('AllData' + datestring + '.xlsm'))#Fill in your path
```

If this does not work, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169731/write-pandas-dataframe-to-xlsm-file-excel-with-macros-enabled) Question which should answer your problem because it is about how to save a excel file with xlsm ending

Comment: Your welcome! If it helped you please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, there may be some VBA code that is embedded in the workbook - hence the `.xlsm` extension.

If you do not need the macro/VBA code try: `wb.save('AllData' + datestring + '.xlsx')`

Also, If you check the `load_workbook()` documentation there is a `keep_vba` argument. try:

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('AllData.xlsm', keep_vba=True)`