# Write to an existing .xlsm using pandas and XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I would like to write a dataframe to an existing .xlsm file which already has content.

[Write pandas dataframe to xlsm file (Excel with Macros enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169731/write-pandas-dataframe-to-xlsm-file-excel-with-macros-enabled) describes how to write to a new file but I want to write to add a new sheet to an existing .xlsm file. When I use the following (as in the question):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'First' : [5, 2, 0, 10, 4], 
                   'Second' : [9, 8, 21, 3, 8]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'test.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1') #This is the df I'm trying to add to the sheet
writer.save()
```

it overwrites the original content and the existing .xlsm file only has the newly added sheet.

I can't quite figure out how to amend the code in the linked question above to consider an existing file.

Thanks

*I have extracted the vbaProject.bin ad described here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html *

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using this XlsxWriter workaround. I think you would need to copy/paste already existing sheets into writer.sheets. Maybe one way to fix it is to add a line like

```
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
```

but this syntax does not work with engine = 'xlsxwriter'

To add a DataFrame to an xlsm sheet what I did is simply :

```
import pandas
import openpyxl

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path, keep_vba= True)
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

dataframe_to_insert.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet_destination)

workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = excel_file_path

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

It seems `keep_vba= True` is doing the job for me (Python 3.8.x).

Comment: This wouldn't work. the 'writer=pandas.ExcelWriter'  line would create an empty 'excel_file_path' file which 'openpyxl.load_workbook' could not subsequently load. You'd have to at least use `mode='a'`. But still would end up with a corrupted workbook most likely.