# How to write pandas dataframe to an existing Macro-Enabled Excel Spreadsheet (.xlsm)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas.excelwriter

I am currently working on a project that require me to write a pandas **DataFrame** to an **EXISTING Macro Enabled Excel File (*.xlsm*)**, and then saved the file as a different (*.xlsm*) file.

EXISTING File: ***"Structure Report Template.xlsm"***, where the ***"Sheet1"*** contains a vba button. I want to write the DataFrame to ***"Sheet2"***.

I hope someone could help with the issue please, thank you in advance for your time.

I have tried to use **[pd.to_excel]**, but it only supports *'.xls'* and *'xlsx'* files. Using *'.xlsm'* extension will cause an error.

I also tried to create workbook object from **openpyxl**, and use **_[workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')]_**, but it also causing the same error when I am trying to open the new excel file:

> Excel cannot open the file 'myFilename.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify > that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import shutil
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

template='Structure Report Template'
new_file_name='VGC Structure Report'
shutil.copy(template,new_file_name)

writer=pd.ExcelWriter(new_file_name+'.xlsm',engine='xlsxwriter')
vgc_endfile.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
workbook=writer.book
workbook.filename=new_file_name+'.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')
writer.save()
```

```py
wb=load_workbook(new_file_name+'.xlsm')
sheet2=wb['Sheet2']
for x in dataframe_to_rows(vgc_endfile):
    sheet2.append(x)
wb.save(new_file_name+'.xlsm')
```

What I want to achieve:

1. open the **'Structure Report Template.xlsm'**
2. write dataframe to **'Structure Report Template.xlsm'** and **"Sheet2"**
3. Save **'Structure Report Template.xlsm'** as **'VGC Structure Report.xlsm'**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170939/7473057 might be helpful?

Comment: Continue to my post:
I have already solved the issue, I discover the **xlwings** library which is compatible with **.xlsm** file, and it also has pandas and numpy built-in. Nice~