# How to update xlsm file since DataFrame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to update an xlsm file using python from a DataFrame. How can I modify that file without errors? My principal problem is this: I overwrite the file and save it, and I when go to open it, the file is corrupt and I can't open it.

```py
def write_data(self, sheet, col_start, row_start):
        with ExcelWriter('TEST.xlsm') as writer:
            self.get_data2post(sheet).to_excel(writer,
                                               startcol = col_start,
                                               startrow = row_start,
                                               sheet_name = sheet,
                                               header = False,
                                               index = False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170939/12240283 Does this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it *can't* save an excel file with macros from *pandas* or *ExcelWriter*. So, I've had to use a different library, *_openpyxl_* and with this, I can read and write an excel file with macros, but... this has a few problems like losing some images, and formulas are not calculated